# How to match a string between two same delimiters?

Tags: java, regex

`some-string-test-moretext.csv`

I want to extract the string `test`, which is always found after the 2nd and 3rd `-` delimiter.

The expression `[-](.*?)[-]` would match `-string-`. So it's probably close, but how can I move on to the next match?

If that matters, I'm using `java`.

Comment: Why not use string.split?

Comment: There are many potential solutions. You could split on `-` and pick third element. You could combine indexOf and substring. You could rewrite your regex to not consume `-` by using look-around mechanisms. But to pick the best one we would need to know more about how your real data can look like.

Comment: What would be matched from `------------------------` ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you know the number of delimiters in advance, you can just split the `String`.

```
String[] test = {
     "some-string-test-moretext.csv",
     "another-string-test-andthensome.csv"
};
for (String s: test) {
    System.out.println(s.split("-")[2]);
}
```

**Output**

```
test
test
```

Comment: Ok that's probably advisable to just split and not using regex here.

Comment: @membersound `split` is using regex to describe delimiter, it just happens that `-` is not regex metacharacter so you don't need to escape it.

Comment: @membersound seems like the easiest and most concise way yes. You *could* use a Pattern/Matcher and iterate until you get the indexed back-reference of your choice, but I can't see this as useful within context.

Answer (score 1):

This should give you quite a good head start:

`[^-]+-[^-]+-(.*?)-[^-]+\.csv`

https://regex101.com/r/YjWDkv/1

Answer (score 0):

I would propose this, using regex, and very short :

```
String str = "some-string-test-moretext.csv\n";

Matcher m = Pattern.compile("\\w+-\\w+-(\\w+).*").matcher(str);
String res = m.find() ? m.group(1) : "";

System.out.println(res);
```

---

For sure`String.split()` is another way :

```
String res = str.split("-")[2];
```

Answer (score 0):

In `sed`:

```
$ echo 'some-string-test-moretext.csv' | sed 's/[^-]*-[^-]*-\([^-]*\)-.*/\1/'
test
```

`[^-]*` means "zero or more occurrences of any char except "-". Let's call that "notHyphen". So we're matching on `notHyphen-notHyphen-\(notHyphen\)-.*` and replacing the whole match with `\1`, that is, whatever is captured by the `\(\)`.

In Java, you won't need to escape `(` to `\(`, and the technique for extracting from capturing groups is different:

```
Pattern patt = Pattern.compile("[^-]*-[^-]*-([^-]*)-.*");

Matcher m = patt.matcher(filename);
String extracted = null;
if (m.matches()) {
    extracted = m.group(1);
}
```